# Bad request exception in OData request

Tags: c#, linq, odata

During the execution of this snippet

```
var res = ctx.Resources.Where(
            t => t.ResourceId == "T/15")
            .First();
```

the program throws a **Bad Request - Error in query syntax** exception.

The problem is the '/' char into the string.

It is important to note that ResourceId is a string and is "the key" of Resources entity.

The special char is mandatory in our system.

Comment: What is the GET URL that is created to query your service when you run it?

Comment: Does `&#47;` work instead of the `/` char?

Comment: @Matteo Galli - have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs since special characters like `/`have to be escaped in OData request. In .Net Framework you could utilize [Uri.EscapeDataString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose, for example:

```
var encResourceId = Uri.EscapeDataString("T/15");
var res = ctx.Resources.Where(
            t => t.ResourceId == encResourceId)
            .First();
```

It is assumed that the specified query will be transformed into the following OData request:

```
http://localhost/odata/Resources()?$filter=ResourceId eq 'T%2F15'
```

Comment: I think that escaping in C# might not be the case. Try following:

`NorthwindEntities c = new NorthwindEntities(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc"));
            var actual = c.Products.Where(p => p.ProductName != "T/15").ToArray();
            Debug.Assert(actual.Length > 0);`

That works just okay and the GET url itself is of course escaped according to Fiddler:
http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products()?$filter=ProductName%20ne%20%27T/15%27

Maybe there are some more details that @Matteo Galli did not share with us.

Comment: Taras, thanks for your comment! Probably you are right since OData request is getting escaped automatically.